# Ошибка: "Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Не могу понять в чем дело. Я понимаю о чем эта ошибка, но я не понимаю почему она возникает, ведь я все сделал правильно. Это мутация:

```
['SET_POSTS'] (state, posts) {
    console.log(posts)
    state.lists.posts = posts
}
```

Ругается на строку `state.lists.posts = posts`.

Если я заменю строку `state.lists.posts = posts` на, например, эту `state.lists.posts = ['posts']`, то ошибка более не возникает.

Строка `console.log(posts)` возвращает массив с объектами. И он помещается (заменяя старый) в хранилище, несмотря на ошибку.

Мутация идет через действие:

```
this.$store.dispatch('posts/setPosts', posts)
```

Строка выше находится в методе, который вызывается директивой `v-on` через `$emit` из дочернего компонента.

Раньше никогда не возникало подобных проблем с этой ошибкой.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем дело?

Comment: `state.lists.posts = [ ...posts ]` или `state.lists.posts = cloneDeep(posts)` с использованием lodash. Для импорта методов lodash лучше всего делать так: `import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash'`

Answer (score 1):

У тебя не мутация, а действие (action)

Вместо

> state.lists.posts = posts

вызови commit мутации, которая это делает